# c++ How to sort an Array in JUCE using ElementComparator Class

Tags: c++, juce

I have an Array , i want to sort this Array using ArrayName.sort(ElementComparator& comparator) , which is defined in JUCE Library, here is the link for the sort function : http://www.rawmaterialsoftware.com/juce/api/classArray.html#a13366b4435364fcd0d304cdcaebd726a

I am not able to understand how to pass that comparator to my sort function.

Or, if anyone can give me a better way to sort the Array of Strings in ascending and descending order.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Not sure about JUCE, but have you considered using a vector of strings, and using a standard sort algorithm?

Comment: If you are intent on using the JUCE library, I would suggest posting the code you have tried and what error you are getting, for further assistance.

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty simple and it is described in the documentation:

> This will use a comparator object to sort the elements into order. The object passed must have a method of the form:

```
int compareElements (ElementType first, ElementType second);
```

> ..and this method must return:
>
> a value of < 0 if the first comes before the second
>      a value of 0 if the two objects are equivalent
>      a value of > 0 if the second comes before the first

So, to sort an Array with an own comparator, you have to define a class that implements the above stated method, for example:

```
class MyArraySorter
{
public:
    static int compareElements(ElementType a, ElementType b)
    {
        if (a < b)
            return -1;
        else if (a > b)
            return 1;
        else // if a == b
            return 0;
    }
};
```

Of course, ElementType has to be the type of element the array is holding and the implementation of the compareElements has to be adapted accordingly.

And then pass it to your array's sort method:

```
MyArraySorter sorter;
myarr.sort(sorter);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Or, if anyone can give me a better way to sort the Array of Strings in ascending and descending order.

An example might be:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<std::string> vec;

/* populate your vector */

std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
```

You can attempt using some of the standard libraries to accomplish storing and sorting strings more easily.